# GROUP BY after ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I need to do `GROUP BY` after `ORDER BY`. I don't understand why MySQL doesn't support that.
This is my code:

```
SELECT
    `pages`.`id`,
    `contents`.`id_language`,
    [...]

[...]

ORDER BY
    FIND_IN_SET(`languages`.`id`, '3') DESC

[the GROUP BY]
```

The results will be something like this:

```
id | id_language | ...
1    3
1    1
2    3
2    5
2    1
```

I need to group by ID, I need only the first result and I need to save in a view. I can't use a SUBQUERY because of that.

The result need to be:

```
id | id_language | ...
1    3
2    3
```

Note: Don't get confused by `id_language = 3`, because it isn't a rule.

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT id, idl
FROM (SELECT
    `pages`.`id` as id,
    `contents`.`id_language` as idl,
    [...]

[...]

ORDER BY
    FIND_IN_SET(`languages`.`id`, '3') DESC
     ) d
GROUP BY d.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Group By will group result sets, and is generally used for aggregation.
Order By is the way that results are sorted.

Comment: So I can't use GROUP BY for this case?

Answer (score 1):

You may want an additional column in your original query that you GROUP BY, along with whatever you're currently grouping by. That column, when grouped, could then be used to order afterward. For instance:

```
SELECT
    SUM(IF(`languages`.`id` = 3, 1, 0)) AS languageOrder,
    `pages`.`id`,
    `contents`.`id_language`,
    [...]

[...]

[GROUP BY...]

ORDER BY languageOrder DESC
```

I would intend for languageOrder to be positive for groups that contain language #3, 0 otherwise. So groups that contain language 3 will be at the top.

Comment: The ORDER BY works fine, the problem is that I need ONLY the first value found for each ID.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, what you really want is that for each group, you want returned whichever row has the 3 in the language_id. If there can be only one (or none) row with a 3, then you can do WHERE language_id = 3. If there can be more than one, how can SQL decide which one to show you?

Comment: Nop... The result is something like `1|3`, `1|5`, `2|2`, `2|5`, for instance... I need get, for each ID, the FIRST FOUND ROW... so, the result for this example is `1|3` and `2|2` only.

Comment: But if the "first" is defined by the ORDER BY, you are essentially searching for the row that has the highest number for ORDER BY... So why can't you use an equivalent WHERE clause?

Comment: That's where I am not understanding. Because the first is not necessarily the highest value. Now I do not know who exactly is confusing, I do not understand your idea, maybe.

Comment: Rows in SQL have no intrinsic "order" to them. They are floating around in the server, and you can either get them in a random-ish order, or by explicitly ordering them using ORDER BY. If you mean first as in the first entered into the database, you must maintain a "timestamp" column and do ORDER BY timestamp. So, what do you mean by "first"?

Comment: The order will depends of user preferences. On my case, the `id_language` specific a ID that represents a language. If I have `1|english`, `2|portuguese`, and user set order preference to `1|2`, the first result found need prefer `1|english`, but get `2|portuguese` case not exists a row for `1|english`. If user set `2|1`, like order preference, then, on this case, the preference is `2|portuguese` and after `1|english`, case don't exists row in portuguese for a specific ID object.

Answer (score 0):

*Very amusing*, try

```
select * from your_table
where id_language=3
order by id;
```

As far I can tell, the rule set is `id_language=3`,
which make no differences from using `where`