# GROUP BY id After ORDER BY time

Tags: mysql, sql

This query returns all items where the difference between the timestamps is less than 180 seconds.

The problem is, after all this is done, I need to then limit the results to the one most recent entry per facebook_id.

I tried using GROUP BY facebook_id, but it doesn't work because if I GROUP BY facebook_id before ORDER BY 'time', it picks the older entry instead of the newer entry which is not what I want.

Is there any way to GROUP BY after ORDER BY?

```
SELECT facebook_id, 
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `time`, '$mytime') AS `timediff`
FROM `table`
WHERE `facebook_id` != $fbid
HAVING `timediff` <= '180'
ORDER BY `time` DESC
```

Thanks for your help!

Note: I did try the suggested solutions to this question but had no success. [GROUP BY after ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310653/group-by-after-order-by)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT fid, timediff
 FROM (
          SELECT facebook_id as fid, 
          TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `time`, '$mytime') AS timediff
          FROM `table`
          WHERE `facebook_id` != $fbid
          HAVING `timediff` <= '180'
          ORDER BY `time` DESC
         ) entries
 GROUP BY entries.fid
```

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a self join by calculating maximum value of time column and join with 2 conditions one with `facebook_id` and second to match the time from table to the `max_time` of second query which will return recent entry against each `facebook_id`

```
SELECT t.*, 
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `time`, '$mytime') AS `timediff`
FROM `table` t
JOIN (
SELECT facebook_id,MAX(`time`) max_time FROM `table` GROUP BY facebook_id
) t1
ON(t.facebook_id= t1.facebook_id AND t.`time` = t1.max_time)
WHERE t.`facebook_id` != $fbid
HAVING `timediff` <= '180'
ORDER BY t.`time` DESC
```

Comment: I really appreciate your time answering the question. I tried cartridgemeadow's solution first and it worked for my needs!